# PostgreSQL saving date in 'Local time zone' while i set it to 'UTC' with Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I m trying to save date in `UTC` format, but it being save in my `localtimezone`  It is okay till `Django view` but after `.save()` it stores in database as 'localtimezone'

my `setting.py`

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_TZ = True
```

`model.py`

```
class Career(models.Model):
"""
model for storing all leads from career section of front apps
"""
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
status = models.BooleanField(default=1)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
updated_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'career_leads'
```

my `views` file

```
class CareerFormApi(APIView):
 def post(self, request):
    career_serializer = CareerPostSerializer(data=request.data)
    career_data = request.data


    if career_serializer.is_valid():
        career_serializer.validated_data['created_on'] = timezone.datetime.now()
        career_serializer.validated_data['updated_on'] = timezone.datetime.now()
        # I am geeting correct time zone here.
         print(timezone.datetime.now()) 


        career_serializer.validated_data['status'] = True

#after save  i check my Database where it saved as my localtime zone

        career_serializer.save() 

        return Response({
            'status': status_code.HTTP_201_CREATED,
            'message': 'Detail has been saved successfully.'
        }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(career_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**P.S.** I have change my `postgres` timezone as well in to `UTC` like this

```
set timezone='UTC';
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: try detaching the timezone from the date field before saving it `datetime_field = self.datetime_field.replace(tzinfo=None)`

Comment: @MaheshHViraktamath it solved,  just need to restart postgresql after changing the timezone , I was missing that.

Comment: My recommendation: **either** use `timestamp with time zone` and handle time zones in the database, **or** use `timestamp without time zone`, store UTC timestamps there and handle time zones in the application. Don't mix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want change timezone of Postgresql, go through this command:

`ALTER USER User_Name SET TimeZone TO 'utc';`

And restart the postgres service through this:

`sudo service postgresql restart`