# Django timezone not working with postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, timezone

I want to show user timezone on my django application. The database is on postgresql server. With the configuration below can not reach my goal.

**Django side:**

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

This is my date field:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now =True)
```

**Postgres side:**
In my database, the field "created" seems to be *aware* of timezone:

```
\d my_table;
Column      |           Type  
created     | timestamp with time zone
```

Here is a sample of data stored in this field. it stores the user's timezone and not the UTC:

```
select created from my_table;
            created
-------------------------------
 2019-02-03 10:05:40.462164+02
```

**Additionnel info:**
- pytz is installed.
- my django app shows the UTC time.

**My question:**
How can I show the timezone to the user? Do you see that there is something wrong with my configuration?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You need to change your Postgresql timezone to `utc`command   `ALTER USER User_Name SET TimeZone TO 'utc';` and restart `postgresql`   `sudo service postgresql restart`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL saving date in 'Local time zone' while i set it to 'UTC' with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54825990/postgresql-saving-date-in-local-time-zone-while-i-set-it-to-utc-with-django)

Comment: No it seems that this solution does not work

Answer (score 2):

You need change  Postgresql timezone to `UTC`.
command:

`ALTER USER User_Name SET TimeZone TO 'utc';`

And restart the postgres service:

`sudo service postgresql restart`